# How to update UIScrollView's ContentView's subviews resolution on UIScrollView zoom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have `UIScrollView`. I also have `UIView` named drawingView for my custom drawing. I added drawingView to `UIScrollview`. This drawing view returns `CATiledLayer` so that on `UIScrollView` zoom, I should not get blurred drawing.

I also have some `subviews` on drawingView like `UITextView` but their resolution don't get update by CATiledLayer and that's why it is showing blurred. What should I do to update drawingView's subview(`UITextView`) resolution?

Following is the demo code. I want, when I zoom `UIScrollView`, the text inside the square should not get blurred.

In DrawingView.m

```
@implementation DrawingView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 4;
    }
    return self;
}

+ layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    [[UIColor orangeColor] setFill];
    [circlePath fill];
}

@end
```

In ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet DrawingView *drawingView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0f;

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 40, 40)];
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textView.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:4];
    [self.drawingView addSubview:textView];
}

#pragma mark - Scroll View Delegates

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.drawingView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are stretching drawingView, On which you have added text field. So if drawing view will zoom then its children's automatically zoom like text field. Correct this then your problem will be solved.